# Angular add custom js file in component

Tags: angular

In angular project I have two online js files with the same name I want to import one of them on specific component depend on certain conditions and not download it to adding in assets.
In this case when I don't need to import them in index.html

Comment: can you share more code ?

Comment: i have to js files like:
`<script src="http://test.com/test.js></script>` 
and another one like:
`<script src="http://test2.com/test.js></script>`
the two files contain the same code and i want to import one of them inside component depend on certain conditions

Comment: what these files do is going to change the html or you need it inside the component 

Comment: it's files for 2 payments but the 2 banks use the same backend but the difference in the URL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use native JavaScript for it:

```js
// Create the script element
const script = document.createElement("script");
script.type = 'text/javascript';
// Set script src depend on condition
script.src = '...';
// Append
document.head.appendChild(script);
```

Comment: it worked but if you have other solutions let me know.